# Wrong date inserting in oracle database using .net oledb

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle

when i try to insert a record through .net using oledb it is inserting wrong data

```
public void param()
{
    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO PARAM_INF(PRM_FRM_DT,PRM_TO_DT) values(to_date('01-Jul-2014'),to_date('01-Jul-2014'))", con) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

result `select prm_frm_dt,prm_to_dt from PARAM_INF;`

```
PRM_FRM_DT         PRM_TO_DT        
------------------ ------------------
20-JUL-01 02:00:00 20-JUL-01 02:00:00
```

But the same insert statement from sqldeveloper or sqlplus result is proper.

```
select prm_frm_dt,prm_to_dt from PARAM_INF;

PRM_FRM_DT         PRM_TO_DT        
------------------ ------------------
01-JUL-14 12:00:00 01-JUL-14 12:00:00
```

Comment: Need help i am seriously in trouble

Comment: I'm guessing it just how the tools your using the default date format

Comment: Parameterized query would properly help; so you don't do text based dates which are subject to the cultures and differences between each server/platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void param()
{
    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO PARAM_INF(PRM_FRM_DT,PRM_TO_DT) values('" + String.Format("{0:yyyy-MMM-dd}", Convert.ToDateTime("01-Jul-2014")) + "','" + String.Format("{0:yyyy-MMM-dd}", Convert.ToDateTime("01-Jul-2014")) + "')", con) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

This will definetly help u... one i had also the same problem...